# How to check if a user exist on firebase auth without signup or signin attempt?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a function like isEmailExist on firebase auth without using:

- createUserWithEmailAndPassword
- signInWithEmailAndPassword
- searching on the real-time or firestore database if it is stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users created by calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`  exist in Firebase Authentication, not in Firestore or Realtime Database (unless you stored them there).

The method you're looking for is called [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)) . If it returns an empty array, the email address is not used by any account. If the email address is used, it returns an array of all providers that are linked to that account.

Comment: is there a good way to work with the new "email enumeration protection"?